# angular ui-router basic state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular JS, and I'm learning `ui-router`. In this basic example I'm not able to configure the routing.

The HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a clss="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">Angular Ui router</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">about</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>This is the homepage</p>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>This is the about</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp',['ui.router']);
routerApp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home',{
            url:'/home',
            templateUrl:'home.html'

        })
        .state('about',{
            url:'/about',
            templateUrl:'about.html'
        });
}]);
```

Here is a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/shrideep/w6n93mqc/10/

Comment: I copied your code from JSFiddle directly into your question. It's fine (and sometimes very useful) to include links to JSFiddle, but users should never be required to go off the site to understand your question. Please make sure your next question is self-contained. Good luck!

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris,Would definitely follow this in next question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed up your code, you can see the full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/w6n93mqc/11/

Basically, you needed to have your angular application inside a root element with the `ng-app` directive so that your JS knows where to hook up to inside your DOM. You also had to link to your templates correctly - I'm not sure how it works with `templateUrl` for jsFiddle sites, but it needs to be a path to a file which contains your template.

Here is the fixed code just in case your link expires:

**Template**

```
<div ng-app="routerApp">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a clss="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">Angular Ui router</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a ui-sref="home">home</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="about">about</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp',['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
      url:'/home',
      templateUrl:'home.html'   
    })
    .state('about',{
      url:'/about',
      templateUrl:'about.html'
    });
  }]);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks Dave.I got that.need to get the basics right.

Comment: No worries :) If you have any other questions just ping me. If you found this answer to be acceptable, please mark as accepted as it may help others in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Your templateUrl in your state should be a path to a file, not an id in a script tag.